# Delete file function calling in intent does not work

Tags: android, csv, android-intent, file-io

I was developing an android application for importing csv file to SQLite.
The work flow of the application is as follows:

1. Delete the old csv files in device using DeleteRecursive function
2. Download csv files through ftp server
3. Import the csv files into database.

When I was trying to add a main menu with a "import button" to call the original activity. The DeleteRecursive function does not work anymore.

Here is the code of DeleteRecursive:

```
void DeleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
            DeleteRecursive(child);

    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

Can anyone tell me why? Is there any special setting for the intent in order to get the write permission?

Comment: please follow the naming convention. `deleteRecursive()` :) and post the logcat please

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this permission in your manifest? (Assuming your files are in external storage)

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

> The DeleteRecursive function does not work **anymore**

I am guessing the problem is not with your logic of `DeleteRecursive()`; it is something else. Print things using the logcat and see what is going on. Try removing the import button and test your app by deleting some dummy files. If it does delete, the problem is with the addition of the button.

Comment: I have read this link. http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html
It seems not necessary to add the permission.However, i will try this first. Thank you, Little Child

Comment: Alwasy post logcat for Android questions. It is hard to say what is going on